# How to display one static row and the remaning dynamic rows in php/html

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have the following code:

```
$compare_array=array_diff_assoc($current_array,$previous_array);
foreach ($compare_array as $key => $value) {

#echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";

echo "<table>
<tr>
    <th>column Name</th>
    <th>Updated data</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>$key</td>
    <td>$value</td>

  </tr>
</table>";


}
```

This gives me the following result:
[image]

Below is my desired result:
[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: OP, I edited your question to try to make sense. If I interpreted what you were trying to say incorrectly, feel free to adjust it.

Comment: @PatrickQ thank you for describing in simple manner

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are `echo`ing the table header within the loop.  That is why it is being rendered for every new row.  Try moving the heading outside of the loop like this:

```
echo "<table>
    <tr>
        <th>column Name</th>
        <th>Updated data</th>
    </tr>";

foreach ($compare_array as $key => $value) {
       echo "<tr>
           <td>$key</td>
           <td>$value</td>
       </tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @mdsaif glad it worked! feel free to upvote or accept this answer if it solved your problem.